# Alternatives uses for small SSDs

Tags: windows, ssd, cache

So are there any alternative uses for small SSDs?  I was recently given a 40 GB SSD and I am reluctant to rebuild my OS just to get Windows on the SSD and everything else on a different drive.

I havent seen any methods to use them as cache (like the z68 mobos).  Anyone have any good ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want something equivalent to the "cache" that you get with the z68-based motherboards then there's always [eBoostr](http://www.eboostr.com/en/) which can cache the most regularly used files to a faster medium which typically would be memory but an SSD is still faster than a HDD...

I suspect that short of installing your operating system on the drive (which is admittedly a bit small these days) then putting your pagefile on the SSD and using it as a cache is as good as it gets.

Comment: +1 to pagefile on SSD, exactly what I had in mind. I would be very interested in knowing the result in fact.

Comment: MS recommends putting the pagefile on SSDs.  Its supposed to really increase performance.

Comment: @Mokubai Does the page file even get used when there is abundant physical memory available?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the location of your User Libraries. Go into your Users folder eg `C:\Users\name\` and rightclick on `My Documents`. In the Location-Tab you can change the location it actually points to, in this case maybe a new folder on your SSD. (more advice [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Redirect-a-folder-to-a-new-location))

Next possibility would be to move your Program Files folder to the SSD, but a quick search on google tells me that this is not reccommended by Microsoft and even if you do it's hard to realize and buggy. Maybe you can play around with symbolic links, but they are reported to cause problems with some programs too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Vista/Win 7, you should be able to use it as ReadyBoost cache for Windows. See: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReadyBoost

Comment: readyboost only works on USB flash media.  Plus readyboost is really only useful on low memory systems.

Comment: @keltari - boot speedup of readyboost should help no matter how much mem you have